# Creating a openlayers enabled web project in eclipse

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm brand new to  creating gis map applications and I am trying to get a web project that uses

```
function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", 
                    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                    {layers: 'basic'} );
            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
            var featurecollection = {
              "type": "FeatureCollection", 
              "features": [
                {"geometry": {
                    "type": "GeometryCollection", 
                    "geometries": [
                        {
                            "type": "LineString", 
                            "coordinates": 
                                [[11.0878902207, 45.1602390564], 
                                [15.01953125, 48.1298828125]]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "type": "Polygon", 
                            "coordinates": 
                                [[[11.0878902207, 45.1602390564], 
                                  [14.931640625, 40.9228515625], 
                                  [0.8251953125, 41.0986328125], 
                                  [7.63671875, 48.96484375], 
                                  [11.0878902207, 45.1602390564]]]
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"Point", 
                            "coordinates":[15.87646484375, 44.1748046875]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "type": "Feature", 
                "properties": {}}
              ]
           };
           var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
           var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(); 
           map.addLayer(vector_layer);
           vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(featurecollection));

        }
```

I've included the OpenLayers.js with the img and theme folders under the WEB-IMF.
When I run it only the text shows, not the map.
Is there something I'm missing.

Comment: @dariapra answer goes in the right direction, but I think you might also have syntax errors in your page. Start with one of the OpenLayers examples and work your way up from there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not calling the function init().

A quick and dirty method to accomplish it would be calling this function from the HTML tag *body*:

```
<body onload="javascript: init();">
```

If you are using JavaScript frameworks like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) or [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can call this function just after the DOM is loaded:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', init);   // Prototype framework
$(document).ready(init);                // JQuery framework
```

Comment: I added the  <body onload="javascript: init();"> and the map didn't show up. Is there something else like geojson I need to install.

Comment: As said by unicoletti, the first step would be checking that there are no syntax errors or of any other kind. In case a needed component has not been loaded, then it would trigger an error message.

Comment: I can get it to show a google map but the coordinates feature is not working. I tried it inside of an installed geoserver instance and the coordinates features didn't work either.